# Wordpress Internal server 500

Tags: wordpress

I have a wordpress site in my local environment, then I transferred it on clients server then I encountered internal server error, when I changed language using `q-translate` plugin but in my local environment it is working.

I have tried:

1. `wp-config` - add memory
2. `php.ini` - put in root directory with
   memoey_limit 2048M

Comment: The reason for this error may be because of a corrupted .htaccess file, memory limit, plugins and also while moving the files you may have missed some files. If you can make sure the above factors. Try to uninstall and reinstall the plugin.

Comment: this is really frustrating, i think it is not about moving because i upload it as zip

Answer (score 0):

Try This,

WPLANG defines the name of the language translation (.mo) file. WP_LANG_DIR defines what directory the WPLANG .mo file resides. If WP_LANG_DIR is not defined WordPress looks first to wp-content/languages and then wp-includes/languages for the .mo defined by WPLANG file.

define( 'WPLANG', 'de_DE' );
define( 'WP_LANG_DIR', dirname(**FILE**) . '/wordpress/languages' );

Comment: by the way i am using q-translate plugin, is that related with WPLANG?

Answer (score 0):

double check .htaccess file, something wrong with ur htaccess. I had this kind of problem so normally i checked and replace .htaccess from local env to new one.